# Modeling a chargeback rate as a function of an approval rate

Tags: regression, logistic, proportion, regression-strategies

I am working on a problem where I would like to estimate chargeback rates for online goods orders as a function of the proportion of orders that are approved (approval rate).

The approval rate is a function of scores determined by a machine learning model for each order. The model tries to determine the likelihood of an order being fraudulent. If the order receives a score above a certain threshold, it is approved; otherwise, it is declined. The approval rate is the proportion of total orders that are approved.

If an approved order turns out to be fraud, it will result in a chargeback. The chargeback rate is the proportion of approved orders that turn out to be fraudulent.

The plot below shows the chargeback rate as a function of the approval rate. This curve was constructed by binning the scores in ntiles and then calculating each bin's cumulative approval rate and chargeback rate.

I am trying to fit a curve to this data to estimate the chargeback rate for hypothetical approval rates greater than the realized approval rate.

[image]

I tried transforming the data by taking the logit of chargeback rate and approval rate so that I could fit a regression line. Because the chargeback rate is 0 for some initial range of approval rates, the transformation results in undefined values.

[image]

I have some questions about my approach and assumptions:

- Is working with cumulative data violating some assumption for OLS?

  - i.e. in the way I have set up the data, the chargeback rate in a certain bin can only be greater or equal to the chargeback rate in the previous bin
- How do I get around the undefined values after the transformation?

  - I tried cutting off the beginning values which could work but ideally I would like to fit all the data (see below image)
  - The other issue is that I am interested in extrapolating beyond the data (for higher approval rates) but even after the transform the data is still curved so the line will underestimate the chargeback rate for higher approval rates. This is the part of the curve that I am most interested in so modeling this correctly (and conservatively) is the primary objective
- Am I even setting up the problem correctly? I think it makes sense but I feel that I might be missing something.

[image]